# --exclude-path flag in jshint command is not excluding the files

Tags: node.js, jshint

I have a jshint command as below:

`jshint "+ pathname +" --config .jshintrc --exclude-path .jshintignore --reporter reporter.js > data/jsFile.json`

This command will create the jsFile.json but will not exclude the paths specified in the `.jshintignore` file.

What could be the reason?

Comment: have you tried `--exclude-path ./.jshintignore`?

Comment: yes, but the result is same